# Getting a whole bunch of server output along with wanted output

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpmailer

When I run the php script I end up with a page that says all this:

2015-09-29 22:01:01 SERVER -> CLIENT: ....[alot of server stuff]
Message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

I only want he message has been sent text to show but for some reason Its showing the whole connecting to smtp ,sending message stuff. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_subject = "New customer requesting information/appointment";
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();

    }
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
       !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From     = "user@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("sendTO@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = $email_subject;
$mail->Body     = $email_message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php

}?>
```

I am using xampp, Apache to run the php script and have only been doing this stuff for about 3 days so I'm sure its a silly mistake/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing debug output. Just set:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

to turn it off.

Comment: Silly mistake as I thought, thanks a ton!